# PowerShell equivalent to grep -f

Tags: powershell, grep

I'm looking for the PowerShell equivalent to `grep --file=filename`. If you don't know `grep`, filename is a text file where each line has a regular expression pattern you want to match.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but `Select-String` doesn't seem to have this option.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

The `-Pattern` parameter in `Select-String` supports an array of patterns. So the one you're looking for is:

```
Get-Content .\doc.txt | Select-String -Pattern (Get-Content .\regex.txt)
```

This searches through the textfile `doc.txt` by using every regex(one per line) in `regex.txt`

Comment: Also, PowerShell tab completion will make commands properly capitalized, so it is not hard to input.

Comment: @joon A couple of years late, but I'd add that Powershell is case insensitive so the capitalization of commands is not an issue.

Comment: @Vache of course - I think my comment above is a reply to another comment, but it seems the comment is gone anymore.

Comment: @dee-see A couple of years late, but I'd add that *Windows* is case insensitive so the capitalization of commands, paths,... is not an issue. :)

Answer (score 131):

```
PS) new-alias grep findstr
PS) C:\WINDOWS> ls | grep -I -N exe

105:-a---        2006-11-02     13:34      49680 twunk_16.exe
106:-a---        2006-11-02     13:34      31232 twunk_32.exe
109:-a---        2006-09-18     23:43     256192 winhelp.exe
110:-a---        2006-11-02     10:45       9216 winhlp32.exe

PS) grep /?
```

Comment: I never understood how this got so many votes. It's doesn't even answer the question..

Comment: What I like about this answer is that `findstr` works the most like `grep` on Linux does. `Select-String` is great for working with objects, but sometimes you just want to match on strings.

Comment: It is worth noting that `findstr` is not native to PowerShell, but Command Prompt.

Comment: This findstr command was already available to me, and it worked just like unix GREP.

Comment: @FrodeF. that's because this question is the first thing comes up when we search for "powershell grep equivalent". :)

Comment: Worth mentioning that `-I` is "insensitive" and `-N` includes the line number, and that in Windows you'd normally use `/i` and `/n`. Also note that the `/r` option for **regex is on by default**. All parameters for `findstr` are currently described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr#parameters). As best as I can tell, you use [`find` (no `str`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/find) to avoid regular expressions.

Comment: Select-String isn't very good at doing line-based context, which grep is great at.

Answer (score 51):

I'm not familiar with grep but with Select-String you can do:

```
Get-ChildItem filename.txt | Select-String -Pattern <regexPattern>
```

You can also do that with Get-Content:

```
(Get-Content filename.txt) -match 'pattern'
```

Comment: Extended this to e.g. `dir *.cs -Recurse | sls "TODO" | select -Unique "Path"`. Thx for the excellent pointer.

Comment: Good to know the alias is `sls` which is faster to write

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue trying to find text in files with powershell. I used the following - to stay as close to the Linux environment as possible.

Hopefully this helps somebody:

**PowerShell:**

```
PS) new-alias grep findstr
PS) ls -r *.txt | cat | grep "some random string"
```

**Explanation:**

```
ls       - lists all files
-r       - recursively (in all files and folders and subfolders)
*.txt    - only .txt files
|        - pipe the (ls) results to next command (cat)
cat      - show contents of files comming from (ls)
|        - pipe the (cat) results to next command (grep)
grep     - search contents from (cat) for "some random string" (alias to findstr)
```

**Yes, this works as well:**

```
PS) ls -r *.txt | cat | findstr "some random string"
```

Comment: That's pretty good, but I also want the name of the file where it was found

Comment: @KenSeehart to get folder/file information you need to pipe that info as well, `cat` loses that info converting everything to string.
You could run this command to achieve what you need `ls -r *.txt | select-string -pattern "some text" | Format-Table LineNumber, Filename, Line`.
Same but with aliases: `ls -r *.txt | sls -pattern "some text" | ft LineNumber, Filename, Line`

Comment: From here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment: 
Mix Linux and Windows commands: In this example, the Linux command `ls -la` is used to list files in the directory, then the PowerShell command `findstr` is used to filter the results for words containing "git": `wsl ls -la | findstr "git"`. This could also be done mixing the Windows `dir` command with the Linux grep command: `dir | wsl grep git`.

Answer (score 12):

So I found a pretty good answer at this link:
https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2011/03/powershell-search-for-string-or-grep-for-powershell/

But essentially it is:

```
Select-String -Path "C:\file\Path\*.txt" -Pattern "^Enter REGEX Here$"
```

This gives a directory file search (*or you can just specify a file) and a file-content search all in one line of PowerShell, very similar to grep. The output will be similar to:

```
doc.txt:31: Enter REGEX Here
HelloWorld.txt:13: Enter REGEX Here
```

Comment: He wants to load the pattern from a file.

Comment: If that is what he is asking, there are other answers that are similar to mine, so I feel like the question may not be worded super clear of desired answer.  But after rereading it, I agree that he probably is wanting to pipe regex from a file into select string.

Answer (score 3):

I find out a possible method by "filter" and "alias" of PowerShell, when you want use grep in pipeline output(grep file should be similar):

first define a filter:

```
filter Filter-Object ([string]$pattern) {
    Out-String -InputObject $_ -Stream | Select-String -Pattern "$pattern"
}
```

then define the alias:

```
    New-Alias -Name grep -Value Filter-Object
```

final, put the former filter and alias in your profile:

> $Home[My ]Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

Restart your PS, so you can use it:

> alias | grep 'grep'

---

**References**

1. alias:
   `Set-Alias` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7.1)
   `New-Alias` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-alias?view=powershell-7.1)
2. `Filter` (Special function) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.1#filters)
3. Profiles (just like .bashrc for bash): [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1)
4. `out-string` (**this is the key**) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-7.1):
   in PowerShell Output is object-based [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7.2#output-is-object-based)，so the key
   is to convert object to string and grep the string.
5. `Select-String` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1):
   Finds text in strings and files

Answer (score 1):

This question already has an answer, but I just want to add that in Windows there is Windows Subsystem for Linux [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop).

So for example if you want to check if you have service named **Elasicsearch** that is in status **running** you can do something like the snippet below in powershell

`net start | grep Elasticsearch`

Answer (score 0):

> but select-String doesn't seem to have this option.

Correct. PowerShell is *not* a clone of *nix shells' toolset.

However it is not hard to build something like it yourself:

```
$regexes = Get-Content RegexFile.txt | 
           Foreach-Object { new-object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex $_ }

$fileList | Get-Content | Where-Object {
  foreach ($r in $regexes) {
    if ($r.IsMatch($_)) {
      $true
      break
    }
  }
  $false
}
```

Comment: This is a bad answer. `Select-String -Pattern somestring` is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Maybe?

```
[regex]$regex = (get-content <regex file> |
foreach {
          '(?:{0})' -f $_
        }) -join '|'

Get-Content <filespec> -ReadCount 10000 |
 foreach {
           if ($_ -match $regex)
             {
              $true
              break
             }
         }
```

Answer (score -2):

Came across this that might be of interest : "mlocate" (yum install mlocate). TO use, type "locate [file]".

Comment: Hello, how is that any related to PowerShell? This doesn't attempt to answer the question.