# Using ADO to query text files - terrible performance

Tags: excel, vba, text-files, ado

I'm writing some code in VBA behind Excel to pull some summary numbers out of potentially huge text files (10M+ rows) out on a network drive. In the past, these numbers have been pulled using greps in linux, but I was hoping to implement something that could be done with a click of a button in Excel for ease of use.

My solution works, but it's like 25 times slower than a linux grep - takes 4 minutes to query 10M records, while the grep can do it in 10 seconds. Should I not be using ADO for this? Why is it so slow, aside from the fact that text files obviously aren't indexed? Is there a better solution that could still be coded without too much hassle in VBA, or is it a lost cause? I'm using Excel 2007 and the ADO 6.0 library. Here is some sample code:

```
Sub RunSQL()

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"";" & _
    "Data Source=\\network\share\path\;"
rs.Open "select count(*) from Customers.tab where CHANGE_FLAG = 'Y'", cn
Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: ADO recordset would be slow if you are fetching too many rows and that too with all the columns. How about powershell (assuming you want to use Windows as you are scripting in VBA)? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199321/powershell-equivalent-to-grep-f) is a good starting point.

Comment: Hmm I will definitely check this out, thanks!