# convert this linux statement into a statement which is supported by windows command prompt

Tags: linux, windows, unix, sed, command

This is my statement supported by unix environment

```
"cat document.xml | grep \'<w:t\' | sed \'s/<[^<]*>//g\' | grep -v \'^[[:space:]]*$\'"
```

But I want to execute that statement in windows command prompt .
How do I do that? and  what are the commands which are similar to cat, grep,sed .

please tell me the exact code supported for windows similar to above command

Answer (score 2):

The double quotes around the pipeline in your question are a syntax error, and the backslashed single quotes should apparently really not have backslashes, but I assume it's just an artefact of a slightly imprecise presentation.

Here's what the code does.

```
cat document.xml |
```

This is a [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) but its purpose is to feed the contents of this file into the pipeline.

```
grep '<w:t' |
```

This looks for lines containing the literal string `<w:t` (probably the start of a tag in the XML format in the file).  The single quotes quote the string so that it is not interpreted by the shell (otherwise the `<` would be interpreted as a redirection operator); they are consumed by the shell, and not passed through to `grep`.

```
sed 's/<[^<]*>//g' |
```

This replaces every pair of open/close brokets with an empty string.  The regular expression `[^<]*` matches zero or more occurrences of a character which can be anything except `<`.  If the XML is well-formed, these should always occur in pairs, and so we effectively remove all XML tags.

```
grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$'
```

This removes any line which is empty or consists entirely of whitespace.

Because `sed` is a superset of `grep`, the program could easily be rephrased as a single `sed` script.  Perhaps the easiest solution for your immediate problem would be to obtain a copy of `sed` for your platform.

```
sed -e '/<w:t/!d' -e 's/<[^<]*>//g' -e '/[^[:space]]/!d' document.xml
```

I understand quoting rules on Windows may be different; try with double quotes instead of single, or put the script in a file and use `sed -f file document.xml` where `file` contains the script itself, like this:

```
/<w:t/!d
s/<[^<]*>//g
/[^[:space]]/!d
```

This is a rather crude way to extract the CDATA from an XML document, anyway; perhaps some XML processor would be the proper way forward.  E.g. `xmlstarlet` appears to be available for Windows.  It works even if the XML input doesn't have the beginning and ending `<w:t>` tags on the same line, with nothing else on it. (In fact, parsing XML with line-oriented tools is a [massive antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/874188).)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation but sed is not a windows command. So  how can I do that in windows?

Comment: I dumped Windows in 1998, partly because of reasons like this, so if you don't want to obtain one of the cross-platform tools I suggest, I don't think I can help you, other than recommending you consider taking the same step to improve your life and sanity.

Comment: yes,  but it shows an error like sed is not a recognised command

Answer (score 0):

May try with "powershell" ?

It is included since Win8 I think, 
for sure on W10 it is.
I've just tested a "cat" command and it works.

"grep" don't but may be adapt like this :
[PowerShell equivalent to grep -f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199321/powershell-equivalent-to-grep-f)
and
https://communary.wordpress.com/2014/11/10/grep-the-powershell-way/

Comment: Thank you but  I am using that code in a program  so I cannot  execute independently in a shell...

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of grep on windows would be `findstr` and the equivalent of cat would be `type`.

Comment: yes I got that two commands but I cannot  get command for " sed"