# Finding running Docker process in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, command, containers

How can I really easy find one running container with the name for example "mongo" or "webhost"  in Powershell win 10 pro?
I'm trying to learn Docker by Udemy. He's teaching in Linux.
He made a container mongo, started it , and used this command in the terminal to find running process:

```
ps aux | grep mongo
```

I tried to do it in powershell in window 10 pro. I googled and found a command like this:

```
tasklist | findstr "mongo"
```

but it didn't find mongo.
then tried new command:

```
tasklist | findstr "docker"
```

and output was like this:

```
λ  tasklist | findstr docker
com.docker.service            5560 Services                   0     12,268 K
com.docker.backend.exe       18280 Console                    6     21,656 K
com.docker.proxy.exe         16988 Console                    6     22,636 K
```

How can I easily find a running container with a specific name like "mongo" or "webhost" in Powershell win 10 pro?

Comment: use this command `docker ps` to list running containers and `docker ps -a` to list all running containers

Comment: It's through Docker . I search something out of docker . in process list of windows.

Comment: I've not tried it on windows, but on linux it super easy `ps aux | grep <container ID here> as you have already mentioned in your question. Have you tried something like `tasklist | FIND "container name or id here"`?

Comment: λ  tasklist | FIND "mongo"
FIND: Parameter format not correct

Comment: as you see my question i tried this:  tasklist | findtsr "mongo" but nothing

Comment: `mongo` is name of container right? you should not find name of container try finding container ID `tasklist | findtsr "container-id-here"`

Comment: `Findtsr` is not a command, do you mean `findstr`?

Comment: yes. you can see in question the correct format .

Comment: Why not just `Get-Process *mongo*`?

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is too late but I hope it still helps someone else.

For PowerShell, we can find the container by using

`docker ps -a | findstr <your container id>`

or

`docker ps -a | findstr <your image>`

(The **container id**, and **image** can be found using the command `docker ps -a`)

In your case, I would suggest `docker ps -a | findstr mongo` (or you can find your container id and find it)

**Explanation**:

As you type `docker ps --help`, they explain

`docker ps`: default shows just running containers (in your case, I am not sure if your containers started already or not, so I would suggest to check using the `-a` option)

`docker ps -a`: this helps to show all containers including the not running containers

`findstr <what you want to find>`: is a [PowerShell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199321/powershell-equivalent-to-grep-f), which is similar to `grep`

**Alternatives:**

If you install Git Bash, you can try with Linux commands and it still works

`docker ps -a | grep <what you want to find>`